# Status code [CANNOT_FREEZE_SELF], for Process Builder

Tags: community, process-builder

I am getting the following error when doing a bulk creation operation.

> Error received from salesforce.com.  Fields [].  Status code
>   [CANNOT_FREEZE_SELF].  Message [The record couldn't be saved because
>   it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow
>   with version ID *******. Flow error messages: This interview has been
>   terminated as another interview in the same bulk execution request
>   failed with the following error: **An unhandled fault has occurred in
>   this flow**
> An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the
>   flow.  Please contact your system administrator for more information. 
>   Contact your administrator for help.].

Does process builder support bulk operations? I guess that the status code means that it might be unable to freeze the table column for inserting the record.

The Process Builder is:

Start :

Object **
When object is created or updated.

A diamond operation which has following condition.

1. Object**.StageName equals picklist "Submit for Approval"
2. Object**.StageName isChanged Boolean True
3. Object**.status__c equals picklist "Rejected"
4. Object**.status__c equals picklist "Draft"

Conditions: Customize the logic

```
1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4)
```

Immediate actions:
Action Name:
Submit for approval

Object:
Object**

Approval Process:
Default Approval Process

Submitter:
Current User

**Stop the process**

Comment: Can you post the process which you are trying to achieve and causing this error. Little bit background could help other members to identify the defect

Comment: Btw, process builder support bulk operations

Comment: I can write some of the steps. But cannot post pics. I will try to write it clearly.

Comment: @SantanuBoral I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: You have a flow that is attempting to Freeze your User account (i.e. keep you active, but prevent logins). This operation is not allowed for the current user, for obvious reasons. You'll need to read your debug logs and figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Got fixed automatically after fresh data import. Dont know how...